# Does the effect of the Jungle Drums upgrade stack with multiple Monkey Villages?

Tags: bloons-td-5

In Bloons TD 5, there is a building called the Monkey Village. It primarily provides upgrades for other towers in its range, and one of these is called Jungle Drums and increases the attack of towers in the range of the village, which leads me to my qustion: If I build multiple Monkey Villages, each upgraded to have Jungle Drums and have the same towers in their range, will the attack speed increase stack, i.e. will the attach speed of the towers in their range increase for each Monkey Village with Jungle Drums?

Comment: To those downvoting, might I learn what you see wrong with this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No matter how many villages you have, this buff, or any buff for that matter, will not stack with multiple villages. 5 villages will have the same effect as one. However, if you have a 4|0 village and a 0|4 village, a tower in range of both of them will receive the effects of both villages.

Answer (score 4):

No, the Jungle Drums effect doesn't stack. However, on older BTD 5 Mobile versions (and Battles) the MIB Call to Arms boost did stack, being able to make towers shoot up to 60 times per second.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately, it does not stack if you put multiple Monkey-Drum-Villages in the same area, I have tested and re-tested this in  game multiple times, for example, one of the times I tested it with 20 of them, and they were all centered around a single 0/0 dart monkey, and the effect was only that of one-fold the advertised amount, as otherwise, it would clearly be a visible change, when you are increasing the effect 20-fold, which would cause a tower that fires once every second to fire about 16.37 times per second, an obvious difference, however, all of these villages only increased his rate of fire by 15%, the advertised benefit that is given to nearby towers, even when there is one village, so, clearly, this effect does not stack, sadly.